# Geodjango OSMWidget is not returning actual coordinates

Tags: django, python-3.x, geodjango

I am using the OSMWIdget in my PointField form. I am able to get the values returned by the widget

{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 13468873.706852857023478, 1639089.007222681771964 ] }

But the thing is, these are not 'standard' coordinates. I had already set my defaults to 'default_lon' : 120.993173,'default_lat' : 14.564752 so I expected to get these as results.

Also I am not saving any 'spatial' objects to spatialite because I only need the lon and lat as primitive dataypes and I would rather stick to having a single database in our project and that db is not a spatial db.

Comment: Can you please provide the part of the code that you are setting the `default_lon` and `default_lat` and anything else that you do with the widget that may be useful?

Comment: I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I also have this issue. Before data is committed to a model (e.g. with `save()`), the OSMWidget insists on holding the coordinates in 3857. Once saved to the database, however, they're converted to 4326. If you do `my.model.objects.get()` and then print your geometry field, it'll correctly display the coordinates as 4326. I don't think this is expected behaviour as there's an argument in `OSMWidget` called `map_srid` which, ostensibly, is there to allow you to specify the SRID if returned coordinates from a form field.